# Authorized access to certain pages

Tags: php, mysql

For my website I have two separate users - Staff and customers and in turn two seperate logins so that a users email address and password wont grant access to the staff. However although once my staff have logged in the pages they have access too are not visible to other users, if the users find the URL and type it in they can still view the link. I want to change this so that if they find the URL and try and view it they are prompted for a login.

I have created a session code that I was told to place a the top of every page I want kept private, however it doesn't work and I wanted to ask if this was wrong.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['staffId']))
$_SESSION['staffId']=$_SESSION['staffId']+1;
else
$_SESSION['staffId']=1;
echo "StaffId=". $_SESSION['staffId'];
session_destroy();
```

In my database I have staffId as a column and staffType as another where I have listed my staff as type S as well as their other details

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are destroying the session, the flow continues and people can see the rest of the page. You can do following:

Set `$_SESSION['staffId']` when a staff is logged in.

Set `$_SESSION['customerID']` when a customer is logged in.

For staff-only pages use:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['staffId']))
    die("Access not allowed for customers");
```

But for customer pages, you still need to check if they are indeed logged in:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['customerID']))
     die("Access not allowed for not logged in members");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, so my 'getstafflogin' page which handles the form I place $_SESSION['staffId'] ? and on the other pages I remove the code I wrote above and put 

if(isset($_SESSION['staffId']))
else
die("Access not allowed"); 

Sorry for the stupid question i'm attempting to teach myself and am quite new to this!

Comment: Exactly. when a staff is logged in, only then you set the $_SESSION['staffId']. For normal users you don't set it at all. Keep in mind that normal users can access 'user pages' without being logged in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it means alot! When I place the code in the other page I receive a syntax error for the line where i have written 'else' : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/unix/student10/w122856/public_html/STF/DropDown.php on line 7

Comment: //do nothing, continue flow is pseudocode. you need to replace it with actual php code, or just a semicolon. see updated answer.

Comment: Sorry that was an unbelievably stupid move on my part! I entered the code but now even when staff is logged in it says 'access not allowed'

Comment: means that you never set $_SESSION['staffId']

Comment: But I did! I set $_SESSION['staffId'] on my getstafflogin page and then put code on the other pages

Comment: did you put the ! in the if statement?

Comment: I did I put it exactly as above

Comment: @user3527721 I gave you the general idea. You still need to debug it!